# Kivy, press a button to open a popup full of buttons

Tags: kivy

====>OK THANKs its works with b.bind(on_press=partial(self.choix_avatar,chemin)) –
I have to lean more about the "callable" function ...

there is something i don't understand about de events in Kivy with a popup events.

With kivy 1.8.0, I think there is a bug with popup

I have  created an original button : 
on_press => create a popup
in this popup there is a Stacklayout within many Buttons

when I press the original button, the on_press is propagated to the buttons of the StackLayout !!!!!
But my popup is not a subwidget of the original button ! So why? 
And i cant' fired any on_press for my buttons once initialized ... 
Any Idea ? Thanks !
R.T.

in the .kv and the .py

```
<AvatarProfil>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    Button:
        size:(60,60)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        on_press:root.changer_avatar()
        background_normal:root.avatar
    Label:
        text:''
        font_size:14
        italic:True
        halign:'left'

class AvatarProfil(BoxLayout):
    auteur=StringProperty('')
    avatar=StringProperty('test/interrogation.png')

    def changer_avatar(self):
        panel=PanelAvatar(w_avatar=self)
        popup = Popup(title='Les Avatars à choisir',content=panel,size_hint=(None,None),size=(600,600))
        popup.open()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AvatarProfil, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class PanelAvatar(StackLayout):


    w_avatar=ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.spacing=(5,5)
        super(PanelAvatar, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.lavatars=[]
        self.w_avatar=kwargs['w_avatar']
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk('test/avatars resized', topdown=False):
                for name in files: 
                    chemin='test/avatars resized/'+name
                    b=Button(background_normal=chemin,on_press=self.choix_avatar(chemin),size_hint=(None,None))
                    self.add_widget(b)
    def choix_avatar(self,file):

        print ('choix de )%s'%(file))
        self.w_avatar.avatar=file
```

here is the  print log : (without any manual button press !!!)

```
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (1).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (1).png
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (10).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (11).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (12).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (13).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (14).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (15).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (16).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (17).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (18).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (19).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (2).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (2).png
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (20).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (21).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (22).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (23).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (24).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (25).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (3).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (3).png
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (4).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (5).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (6).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (7).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (8).jpg
choix de )test/avatars resized/avatar (9).jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, you're calling `choix_avatar()` when you mean to just bind it.

```
b=Button(background_normal=chemin,on_press=self.choix_avatar(chemin),size_hint=(None,None))
```

Try this:

```
b=Button(background_normal=chemin, size_hint=(None,None))
b.bind(on_press=lambda *_: self.choix_avatar(chemin))
```

Comment: its works with  b.bind(on_press=partial(self.choix_avatar,chemin))